# How to get result of method called inside of a mocked class

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

There is a way to get the result returned from a method called into a mocked object?

For example, if I have the following classes and an interface:

**DoSomethingClass.cs**

```cs
public class DoSomethingClass
{
  
  IInternalClass _intClass;

  public DoSomethingClass(IInternalClass intClass)
  {
    _intClass = intClass;
  }
  
  void DoSomething(int number)
  {
    // do some transformation to the number, e.g.
    var transformedNumber = number * (number - 1);
    
    var x = _intClass.IsEven(transformedNumber);

    // do something else
  }
}
```

**InternalClass.cs**

```cs
public interface IInternalClass
{
  bool IsEven(int number);
}

public class InternalClass: IInternalClass
{
  
  public InternalClass();
  
  public bool IsEven(int number)
  {
    return number % 2 == 0;
  }
}
```

And a test class:

**Tests.cs**

```cs
public class Tests
{
  [Fact]
    public async Task test_something()
    {

        //PREPARE
        var request = 10

        var internalMock = new Mock<IInternalClass>();
        var classToTest = new DoSomethingClass(internalMock.Object);

        // ACT

        await classToTest.DoSomething(request);

        //ASSERT

        //Here I want to check if the method IsEven of the internal class return the right result
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to assert is the return value of the method `IsEven` of the `InternalClass` called inside the main method `DoSomething`, there is no way that I can know the `transformedNumber` calculated inside this method and passed to `IsEven`.

> NOTE: I use the `Moq` library to mock object.

Excuse me for the stupid example above, but I don't have any simple real code to show here, however I hope this can be sufficient to understand the question.

Comment: InternalClass is supposed to implement IInternalClass interface, isn't it?

Comment: Yes @MoRRt, I put it in the same file of InternalClass

Comment: okay, I guess InternalClass : IInternalClass is easier to understand.

Another thing I wanted you to pay attention is   var result = await classToTest.DoSomething(request);
DoSomething() method doesn't return anything because of void.

Talking about the question in case DoSomethingClass.DoSomething method return something you will able to check only the result of this method (or you'll able to provide some ref/out param to pass the result of calling _intClass.IsEven(transformedNumber) outside).

Comment: But in my opinion, if we are talking about unit testing it'd better prepare unit tests for InternalClass and its all class objects (which you need to test) separately.
Because currently from your code example I can see only test_something() test for DoSomethingClass.DoSomething() method, so test_something() is testing the whole  DoSomethingClass.DoSomething() method logic.
Testing InternalClass.IsEven() method could be as another unit test

Comment: Thanks for the comments. They are oversights, unfortunately I took an example already done and changing it quickly I forgot to check certain things. I've fixed the code just now.

Comment: okay, @Piccio95, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to verify that your IsEven method is called on the mocked IInternalClass?

If that is the case then you can use the Verify method on the mock as follows:

```
[Fact]
public void DoSomething_Verify()
{
    var request = 10;
    var internalMock = new Mock<IInternalClass>();
    var classToTest = new DoSomethingClass(internalMock.Object);

    classToTest.DoSomething(request);

    //Verify that the mock is invoked with the expected value, the expected number of times
    internalMock.Verify(v => v.IsEven(90), Times.Once);
    //There are lots of other options for Times, e.g. it is never called with an unexpected value maybe.
    internalMock.Verify(v => v.IsEven(91), Times.Never);
}
```

Also to call the DoSomething method with await you would need to change the method signature as follows:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync(int number)
{
    // do some transformation to the number, e.g.
    var transformedNumber = number * (number - 1);

    var x = _intClass.IsEven(transformedNumber);

    // do something else
}
```

Then you can create a unit test like this:

```
[Fact]
public async void DoSomething_VerifyAsync()
{
    var request = 10;
    var internalMock = new Mock<IInternalClass>();
    var classToTest = new DoSomethingClass(internalMock.Object);

    //To call the DoSomething method with await the method needs the async Task and a good convention is to append Async to the name
    await classToTest.DoSomethingAsync(request);

    //Another slightly more generic option is to verify that the mock was called with and int exactly n Times
    internalMock.Verify(v => v.IsEven(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Exactly(1));
}
```